# C3.js make area chart not opaque

Tags: d3.js, charts, c3.js

Im following using this example : http://c3js.org/samples/chart_area_stacked.html

I am going to make an area chart for many dataSets and I want to make it so the area chart is not see through. Is there any property I can set or class I can add that will make it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the opacity to make the areas opaque by overriding below css rule:-

```
.c3-area {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Note:- Markers and tooltip vertical line is not visible fully because of side-effects.

Which looks as shown below:-

[image]

Comment: This is great! Is there a class I can override when I hover on the legend? It turns it back to opaque.

Comment: .c3-focused and .c3-defocused are the two class which you can override.

Comment: thanks for this. [C3's docs](http://c3js.org/reference.html#class-c3-area) is literally an ellipsis (...). Not sure why they leave all their class selectors blank